# Problem with PHPExcel

Tags: php, xls, phpexcel

I have a simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(225) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

I'm using PHPExcel to export tha table in XLS format.
I wrote a simple PHP lines:

```
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "svn_register";

mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname);

// require the PHPExcel file
require 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';

// simple query

$query = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER by id DESC";

if ($result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error())) {
    // Create a new PHPExcel object
   $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('List of Cities');

   // Loop through the result set
    $rowNumber = 1;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
       $col = '';
       foreach($row as $cell) {
          $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowNumber,$cell);
          $col++;
       }
       $rowNumber++;
   }
   // Save as an Excel BIFF (xls) file
   $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');

   header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="myFile.xls"');
   header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

   $objWriter->save('php://output');
   exit();
}
echo 'a problem has occurred... no data retrieved from the database';
```

I get an empty page.

Comment: What's $rownumber after the loop exits? Any data getting out of the query at all?

Comment: I dont' see where you are getting your column from.
`$col = '';`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I stated this several time when you originally raised thsi question... that script will generate a blank page.

```
$objWriter->save('CityList.xls');
```

writes the Excel workbook to a file called CityList.xls on the server's filesystem. It does **NOT** display anything to the screen... therefore the screen ***will*** be blank.

Look on the server. Find the file called CityList.xls. Open that file in MS Excel.

**EDIT**

Alternatively, set the appropriate headers, and save to php://output

```
// connection with the database
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "database";

mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname);

// require the PHPExcel file
require 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';

// simple query

$query = "SELECT id FROM users ORDER by id DESC";

if ($result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error())) {
    // Create a new PHPExcel object
   $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('List of Cities');

   // Loop through the result set
    $rowNumber = 1;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
       $col = 'A';
       foreach($row as $cell) {
          $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowNumber,$cell);
          $col++;
       }
       $rowNumber++;
   }
   // Save as an Excel BIFF (xls) file
   $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');

   header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="myFile.xls"');
   header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

   $objWriter->save('php://output');
   exit();
}
echo 'a problem has occurred... no data retrieved from the database';
```

**EDIT 2**

Alternative:

```
// Loop through the result set
$rowNumber = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray(array($row),NULL,'A'.$rowNumber++);
}
```

should also fix this error

**EDIT #3**

To add a heading row.

```
$rowNumber = 1;
$headings = array('Name','EMail','Phone');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray(array($headings),NULL,'A'.$rowNumber);

$rowNumber++

// Loop through the result set
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
   $col = 'A';
   foreach($row as $cell) {
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowNumber,$cell);
      $col++;
   }
   $rowNumber++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Very strange I get an error: `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\Classes\PHPExcel\Worksheet.php on line 2103`

Comment: OK! Now we're getting somewhere. The Invalid argument is a genuine error in the fromArray() method. As an alternative to using fromArray(), use the re-edited version of the while loop in my example above.

Comment: OMG `
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Invalid cell coordinate AARRAY' in C:\xampp\htdocs\2011\register\web\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell.php:501 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\2011\register\web\Classes\PHPExcel\Worksheet.php(959): PHPExcel_Cell::coordinateFromString('AARRAY') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\2011\register\web\Classes\PHPExcel\Worksheet.php(860): PHPExcel_Worksheet->getCell('AArray') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\2011\register\web\xls.php(31): PHPExcel_Worksheet->setCellValue('AArray', '115') #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\2011\register\web\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell.php on line 501`

Comment: Im sorry for this terrible message

Comment: My bad: $row should have been $rowNumber in the line $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowNumber,$cell);

Comment: Another error :( `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Invalid cell coordinate 1' in C:\xampp\htdocs\2011\register\web\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell.php:501 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\2011\register\web\Classes\PHPExcel\Worksheet.php(959): PHPExcel_Cell::coordinateFromString('1') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\2011\register\web\Classes\PHPExcel\Worksheet.php(860): PHPExcel_Worksheet->getCell('1') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\2011\register\web\xls.php(31): PHPExcel_Worksheet->setCellValue('1', '1') #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\2011\register\web\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell.php on line 501`

Comment: Can you please take these specific questions to the PHPExcel forums... it's a lot easier for me to answer there rather than constantly eithe rediting my response here, or writing comments.

Comment: The answer to the problem is that you're initialising $col to '', not to 'A'... Excel column lettering begins with 'A' for the first column; same as the first row in an Excel worksheet is row 1.

Comment: Wow It works like magic :) Can I ask for the last thing please? I want to add a name for the first cols: (Name - Email - Phone). I'm in love with PHPExcel :)

Comment: Another Wow. Thanks `$rowNumber++` should be `$rowNumber++;` LOve PHPExcel