# Exporting a php table to Excel

Tags: php, export-to-excel

I am workin on a php assignment...i am new in php..and have developed a cart...i would like user to have an option of clicking a button and exporting the table data i generated to excel..

This is my code so far:-

```
    <?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["customer"])) {
    header("location: customer_login.php"); 
    exit();
   }
//error script
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','1');
//connect to the database
include "../storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
?>
<?php
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//               SECTION ONE
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if(isset($_POST['pid'])){
   $pid=$_POST['pid'];
   $wasFound=false;
   $i=0;

   //if the cart session is set or empty
if(!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"])< 1){
   //Runs if the cart is empty
   $_SESSION["cart_array"]= array(0 => array("item_id"=>$pid,"quantity"=>1));   
 }else{
   //Runs if the cart has at least one item in it
   foreach($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item){
    $i++;
   while(list($key,$value)= each($each_item)){
   if($key == "item_id"&&$value==$pid){
//the ite is in the cart..hence we adjust the quantity
   array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"],$i-1,1,array(array("item_id"=>$pid,"quantity"=>$each_item['quantity']+1)));
   $wasFound=true;
   }//close if conditio
   }//close while loop
  }//close foreach loop
  if($wasFound==false){
  array_push($_SESSION["cart_array"],array("item_id"=>$pid,"quantity"=>1));
   }
  }
  header("location: cart.php");
}
?>
<?php
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//               SECTION TWO
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//if usser chooses to empty their sopping cart
   if(isset($_GET['cmd'])&& $_GET['cmd']=="emptycart"){
      unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
      }
?>
<?php
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//               SECTION THREE
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//if usser chooses to empty their sopping cart
   if(isset($_POST['item_to_adjust'])&& $_POST['item_to_adjust']!=""){
      //execute some code
      $item_to_adjust=$_POST['item_to_adjust'];
      $quantity=$_POST['quantity'];
      $quantity=preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '',$quantity);
      if($quantity >= 1000){$quantity=999;}
      if($quantity < 1){$quantity= 1;}
      $i=0;
   foreach($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item){
    $i++;
   while(list($key,$value)= each($each_item)){
   if($key == "item_id"&&$value==$item_to_adjust){
//the ite is in the cart..hence we adjust the quantity
   array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"],$i-1,1,array(array("item_id"=>$item_to_adjust,"quantity"=>$quantity)));
   }//close if conditio
   }//close while loop
  }//close foreach loop
 }
?>
<?php
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//               SECTION FOUR
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if(isset($_POST['index_to_remove'])&&$_POST['index_to_remove']!=""){
      //access the array and run code to remove
   $key_to_remove= $_POST['index_to_remove'];
if(count($_SESSION["cart_array"])<=1){
   unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
}else{
   unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]["$key_to_remove"]);
   sort($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
   }
}
?>
<?php
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//               SECTION FIVE
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$cartOutput="";
$cartTotal="";
   if(!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"])< 1){
      $cartOutput="<h2 align='center'>Your Cart Is Empty</h2>";
}else{
   $i=0;
   foreach($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item){
   $item_id=$each_item['item_id'];
   $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$item_id' LIMIT 1");
   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
      $product_name=$row["product_name"];
      $price=$row['price'];
      $details=$row['details'];
   }
      $pricetotal= $price*$each_item['quantity'];
      $cartTotal=$pricetotal + $cartTotal;

       //setlocale(LC_MONETARY,"en_KSHs");
      //$pricetotal= money_format("%10.2n", $pricetotal);
      //dynamic table assembly

      $cartOutput .="<tr align='center'>";
      $cartOutput .='<td><a href="../home.php?id=' . $item_id . '">' .$product_name . '</a><br/><img src="../inventory_images/' . $item_id . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name . '" width="40" height="52" border="1"/></td>';
      $cartOutput .='<td>' . $details . '</td>';
      $cartOutput .='<td><form action="cart.php" method="post">
      <input name="quantity" type="text" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '" size="1" maxlength="3" />
      <input name="adjustBtn' . $item_id . '" type="image" value="change" src="../images/buttons/button_save.gif"/>
      <input name="item_to_adjust" type="hidden" value="' . $item_id . '" />
      </form></td>';
      //$cartOutput .='<td>' . $each_item['quantity'] . '</td>';
      $cartOutput .='<td>' . $price . '</td>';
      $cartOutput .='<td>' . $pricetotal . '</td>';
      $cartOutput .='<td><form action="cart.php" method="post">
      <input name="deleteBtn' . $item_id . '" type="image" value="X" src="../images/buttons/button_delete.gif"/>
      <input name="index_to_remove" type="hidden" value="' . $i . '" /
      ></form></td>';
      $cartOutput .='</tr>';
      $i++;
   }

  $cartTotal="<div align='right'>Your Total is KSHs. ".$cartTotal."</div>";
 }
?>
```

Comment: Oh, and do you mean e.g. a MySQL table?

Comment: @Oli maybe that's a different way to say, "I have no code yet" :)

Comment: Exporting to CSV might be easier than to full Excel format, and it can be open by Excel anyway.

Comment: @André - It's as easy to export to full Excel format as it is to CSV, if you use one of the PHP libraries that can write xls/xlsx files

Comment: @Mark: PHPExcel is in fact very easy to use, but I was thinking more about dependency management, data portability, etc. If possible, I think that choosing simple text formats tends to be a better choice.

Comment: Went thru all your comments tried everything but still doesnt work and hehehehe,,,now am more confused than i was before...is the problem in my code?? i just dont get it...Please help...Thanks @Andre its ok if you can even explain how i can export it to CSV...and wat i can do with my code to acheive that..

Comment: @Mahmoud: writing an CSV file is as easy as opening it and using [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) to write an array.

Answer (score 4):

If you absolutely need to export the data to a native Excel file have a look at [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/). It's an excellent library for manipulating Excel files but it would be complicated for a newcomer to PHP. Otherwise, if you're happy exporting as a CSV and converting to an Excel file later look at the native fputcsv() function.

Comment: Went thru all your comments tried everything but still doesnt work and hehehehe,,,now am more confused than i was before...is the problem in my code?? i just dont get it...Please help...Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There's a working example of using the [PHPexcel](http://www.phpexcel.net) library to export data from a SQL query (database table) to an Excel (xls) file in my response to [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748067/problem-with-phpexcel), demonstrating just how easy it actually is.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=catalogo.xls");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0"); 

$table = "<table>";
$table .="<tr><td>Hello world</td></tr>";
$table .="</table>";

echo $table
?>
```