# Export tables which are fetched using submit query to Excel In PHP

Tags: php, excel

I am trying to export tables into excel. the tables in my query are selected using submit, for example :- Date1 and Date2 and type (From dropdown) is selected, then on submit, the table based on type will appear, and i want to export it to excel.

Comment: What did you already try? Did you already Google this problem? If you're unsure on how to proceed, split up your problem in multiple steps and think about solving each step.

Possible solutions: export your data as Comma Separate Values (CSV) file, which can easily be loaded in Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely need to export the data to a native Excel file have a look at [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/). It's an excellent library for manipulating Excel files but it would be complicated for a newcomer to PHP. Otherwise, if you're happy exporting as a CSV and converting to an Excel file later look at the native fputcsv() function.

Also check this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748067/problem-with-phpexcel)

You can try this to simple put php variable to excel using fputcsv().

```
define('CSV_PATH','csvfiles/'); // specify CSV file path

$csv_fileoutput = CSV_PATH . "output.csv"; // Name of your CSV file 
$csvfileoutput = fopen($csv_fileoutput, 'a');

fputcsv($csvfileoutput, array($productnumber,$id,$name,$address,$phone_no));
// php variable which stores value of mysql query.
```

Comment: i am new to PHP..I dont know how to implement PHP Excel.

Comment: these attributes as u mentioned above are not fixed, my table will change according to type selected.

Comment: so you can store mysql row value in php variable like if you use mysql_fetch_array() then row[0] value can be store in $phpvar1 and so on then store this variable using fputcsv.

Comment: Sorry I didnt get that

Comment: my Query is divided into 4 steps.... Search , fetch , display and export. search will fetch different tables based on type selected , upto display its working properly. now i want to export the selected table.how can i do ??

Comment: are you storing data in html tables ?? show me how your data is displayed. Also I am not able to post answer here ..

Comment: yes m storing in html tables..

Comment: if(isset ($_POST['export'])){
if (is_array($result)){
 
$fp = fopen('file2.csv', 'w');

foreach ($result as $row) {
    fputcsv($fp, $row);
}

fclose($fp);
echo $result;
}
}

Comment: i did this coding on export button...but nothing is being viewed...no page no table

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078544/export-to-csv-using-jquery-and-html/16203218  and here https://editor.datatables.net/examples/extensions/exportButtons.html

Comment: in these links....work is being done only on one table...and second link works correctly but my query is based on submit selection..m stuck..someone suggested me to apply the code for foreach array..but no working

Comment: Show me your code. I can not figure out like this..